# Horizontal Table in Apex

Tags: salesforce, html-email, apex

I am getting stuck in horizontal table(apex) which I need to share inside the email template.Table structure would be like below:

[Html Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2oM9p.png)

Earlier, I am giving space between them by using ensp; or nbsp; but whenever the data is filling out in these fields, their alignment is not coming correctly.So that I need table instead of using these ( or )

Comment: Is it normal html template or visualforce? The online editor of normal templates might not be good enough for tables. Do you have developer tools like sfdx, vscode to deploy the template from your machine? Or in a pinch you could try making the table in ms word for example and paste it into editor...

Comment: Yeah It is not html template. We are not using VF page. Using developer console.

Comment: I don't understand. Not html template, not visualforce template (vf page and vf email templates are 2 different things). What is it then? Some managed package's own document merge / email template solution?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to make a couple of assumptions here. If these assumptions are wrong, you're kind of SOL.

1. that you're using a Visualforce Email template
2. that your comfortable writing both the visualforce and the apex controller
3. You're aware of how to get a handle on the necessary objects and fields you want to display

If those three things are true, this is actually just an example of how weird visualforce can be.

Visualforce allows you to mix in regular HTML, so the HTML for a table like your image would look something like this:

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">OpportunityNameVar</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>AccountNameVar</td>
      <td>Opp Type</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Phone</td>
      <td>CloseDate</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Hello Kavin, thanks for your reply, I have been implemented in different way. :)